# the class doesn't update in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In my project i have a class `User`. This class contains a subclass `Person`. their relation is oneToOne and unidirection. From `User` to `Person`.  When i read `User` class it load very well. also `Person` load with it.
But the problem is when i will update `Person` class separately. You can see my classes in the following:

```
package entity;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

private int id;
private String username;
private String password;
private Person person;
private int role;

@Id @GeneratedValue
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "username")
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}
public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}

@Column(name="role")
public int getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(int role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

}

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {

private int id;
...

@Id 
@Column(name="user_id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

**Update**
when i use the following code it run without any problem but database doesn't update.

```
@Override
    public void update(Person p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.update(p);
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: You didn't say what is wrong.

Comment: Person doesn't have any field except its ID, which may not be changed. So how could you update it? Show us the code you're executing, what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: person have several integer and string field. i remove it in this page. see `...` under id

Comment: Where is your transaction handling code? Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged